# What is the name of the disk partitioner used during installation?

Tags: partitioning

What is the name of the disk partitioner used during installation?

I want to use the same one to partition disks, etc. I saw a demonstration where someone was using it to partition additional drives, LV's, etc. They were running it from the command line. I would like to use it instead of fdisk.

Would someone please provide the name of the executable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe, the package responsible for doing installation and hence the partitioning stuff is [`ubiquity`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity).

It's dependency includes `libparted0debian1` package which provides the main library doing the partitioning stuff. ( you can see this with `apt-cache depends ubiquity` command ). But the main executable **program** used to do partitioning is `partman` and `partman_server` which are programs [included in ubiquity](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/ubiquity/filelist). Also the installation log file `/var/log/installer/partman` indicating this.

I removed `parted` from Live session and installed Ubuntu without it successfully. Though I have to remove also `usb-creator-gtk` package.

**`partman` program is not intended for normal use**. See the [**Warning!**](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/partman-auto) section in the package description in debian site. This program is not packaged as a standalone but included in `ubiquity` package instead in Ubuntu.

There are many front-end programs available for normal use. A good GUI alternative is  gparted. [gparted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted) [image: Install gparted]

---

I found that [`partman`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/partman-auto) is a seperate package in debian, but it is not in Ubuntu. The program is included in `ubiquity` package.

Answer (score 1):

It should be [parted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/parted) [image: Install parted]
, the partitioning tool.

That's the backend used by Ubiquity (the graphical installer) to partition disks during installation. See [`man parted`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/parted.8.html) for documentation about how to use it directly from the command-line. You will, of course, have to run it as root (`sudo parted`).

Comment: I am aware of parted however that is not the curses version is it? I should have stated that I am looking for the curses partition guide that the installation uses.

Comment: Yes it is the cursed partition guide

Comment: The disk partitioner during installation is not parted (to my surprise). It is `partman` which is included in `ubiquity` package

Answer (score 0):

[parted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Parted) is the backend generally used by most of the partitioners used on linux - You can find the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/parted) for it here. The manual I see seems to state that ext3 support dosen't work, but you'd want to check that with the manpage on the same distro.

If you're working with lvms you'd also need `pvcreate` to create the volumes, `vgcreate` to create the volume group, and `lvcreate` to create the logical volume - there's a howto [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/how-to-create-lvm/) and elsewhere - neither parted nor fdisk will do that.